# aspx Updatepanel not updating - contains Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I am trying to write some data to a database and then update the gridview with the updated data. There is a nested gridview inside the other. I also have two update panels. The child gridview is inside parent updatepanel. at the end of parent updatepanel, child update panel starts, that has a button.

On click I have managed to write to the DB, using find control, I can find the dynamic gridview, re-bind it to the data source. I can also find the child updatepanel and I am using the update method. but it is not updating. I am getting no errors.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <img alt="" runat="server" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
          <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="City" />
        </Columns> 
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:UpdatePanel id="pnChild" runat="server" CssClass="ChildGrid" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="MyButtonClick" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

C Sharp code:

```
GridView gvOrder = gvr.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
gvOrder.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select top 10 * from Orders where CustomerId='{0}'", cID));
gvOrder.DataBind();
UpdatePanel uPanel = gvr.FindControl("pnlOrders") as UpdatePanel;
uPanel.Update();
```

Html output:

```
<table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvCustomers" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Contact Name</th><th scope="col">Contact Name</th><th scope="col">City</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>

                    <img src="images/plus.png" alt="" style="cursor: pointer" />
                     <div id="gvCustomers_pnlOrders_0">

                         <div>
                <table class="ChildGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvCustomers_gvOrders_0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Contact Name</th><th scope="col">City</th>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td style="width:150px;">1</td><td style="width:150px;">19-05-18</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td style="width:150px;">12</td><td style="width:150px;">25-05-18</td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
           <div id="gvCustomers_pnChild_0" CssClass="ChildGrid">

           <input name="gvCustomers$ctl02$TextBox1" type="text" id="gvCustomers_TextBox1_0" />
           <input name="gvCustomers$ctl02$TextBox2" type="text" value="1" id="gvCustomers_TextBox2_0" />
           <input type="submit" name="gvCustomers$ctl02$Button1" value="Button" id="gvCustomers_Button1_0" />

            </div>
```

The HTML layout looks wrong, but that's because I have only posted output of one row. There are no layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `UpdateMode="Conditional"` then you have to set the `ChildrenAsTriggers="False"`.

And [manually trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) your button(s) or other controls events as `AsyncPostBackTrigger` like:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

and manually update your updatepanel as `yourupdatepanel.Update()`:

```
UpdatePanel uPanel = gvr.FindControl("pnlOrders") as UpdatePanel;
uPanel.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that too, still nothing. If I wrap a update panel around the whole site, then it works, but I'm trying not to resort to that option just yet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with nesting of the panels. I changed the child updatepanel to just a panel and all seems to be working without needing a trigger declaration.